# How to run tensorflow in Windows power shell?

Tags: python, powershell, tensorflow, anaconda

I am learning tensorflow to implement deep neural network. I first tried downloading tensorflow using pip, but it doesn't work even though I have upgraded my python version. So I turned to use Anaconda to install tensorflow and it works. However, I now realize that if I want to import tensorflow in python, I have to run the code in the Anaconda Prompt, while I used to use Windows Power Shell(my computer is system is 64-bit windows 10) to run my python code. Is there a way to enable me to run tensorflow(installed by using Anaconda) in Windows Power Shell? It's a bit inconvenient to jump back and forth.

Comment: Unfortunately it’s not something anaconda plans on supporting. I can’t find the issue in their git at the moment, but many people have brought it up and their answer is something along the lines of “supporting the cmd line is the minimum requirement for Windows so that’s all we are going to do”

Answer (score 1):

The "anaconda prompt" is simply calling a batch file called `activate.bat` to setup the environment. Just call it from powershell.

To find the right command line, right click on the anaconda prompt icon, then "Properties", what you are looking for is in "Target". (Replace `%windir%` with whatever works in PowerShell).

E.g in my environment,

```
c:\windows\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\1735003\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\1735003\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3
```

Comment: Can you further explain "whatever works in PowerShell"? What should I look for?

Comment: In the example I gave, I replaced `%windir%` with `c:\windows`, but you could use powershell to get environment variables.